# I'm not able to delete all rows in mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, try-catch, resultset

Hello I want to delete all rows in my mysql table called "kosik" and pass them to another table called "obj_zoznam".

I'm using this code in java:

```
String orderstatus = "Accepted";
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt2 = con.createStatement();
            stmt3 = con.createStatement();

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ID as idzaz, ID_pouzivatela as idpou, ID_tovaru as idtov, cena as suma, ks as kusy from kosik order by ID limit 1");

            while (rs.next()) {

                int zaz = rs.getInt("idzaz");
                int pou = rs.getInt("idpou");
                int tov = rs.getInt("idtov");
                int suma = rs.getInt("suma");
                int kusy = rs.getInt("kusy");

                String sstr = "insert into obj_zoznam (ID_pouzivatela, ID_tovaru, suma, ks, stav) values ("
                        + "'" + id_usera + "', "
                        + "'" + tov + "', "
                        + "'" + suma + "', "
                        + "'" + kusy + "', "
                        + "'" + orderstatus + "')";

                String sstr2 = "delete from kosik where ID = " + zaz;

                stmt2.executeUpdate(sstr);
                stmt3.executeUpdate(sstr2);
            }

            stmt.close();
            stmt2.close();
            stmt3.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Error in writing: " + e.toString());
        }
```

However this code always delete only one record from table "kosik". I'm trying to figure how to delete all records in this table.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I will be very grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `LIMIT 1` from your `SELECT` so you bring up all records and not just 1. On this line:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ID as idzaz, ID_pouzivatela as idpou, ID_tovaru as idtov, cena as suma, ks as kusy from kosik order by ID limit 1");
```

Remove the limit 1:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ID as idzaz, ID_pouzivatela as idpou, ID_tovaru as idtov, cena as suma, ks as kusy from kosik order by ID");
```

Do NOT remove the `WHERE` from the `DELETE` or you will select 1 record (`stmt`), insert it on the other table (`stmt2`) and then clear all the table before inserting all the other records in `obj_zoznam` (`stmt3`).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add to my question that this code always copy only one record to table "obj_zoznam". I want to copy all records and delete these records after they are copied.

Comment: @TomSmith this is the solution for that. The while loop will be executed for each record that you bring up from the select on the first query. Limit 1 was restricting the result set to only 1 record, removing it will select all records and the loop will insert the data on the other table and remove it with the delete (for each record). Put a breakpoint inside the loop and you will see it will be reached many times.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to figure how to delete all records in this table.

Then remove that filter `where` condition from your `delete` statement

```
delete from kosik
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add to my question that this code always copy only one record to table "obj_zoznam". I want to copy all records and delete these records after they are copied.

Answer (score 0):

you limit the result from the query to one row, so you always will have only one id.
the execution of the sstr2 will always delete records with first id

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the entries retaining the table structure, using the truncate command should work.

```
truncate table kosik
```